# Inferring TypeScript array without losing indices

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to write typing for a function I'm writing.
I made it more simple to understand using this straightforward code example:

```js
const getValues: <T extends Array<() => any>>(
  ...args: T
) => T extends Array<() => infer R> ? R[] : null = (...args) =>
  args.map((arg) => arg());

const values = getValues(
  () => "a",
  () => 123
);
```

I want `values` to be of type `[string, number]` but instead it's of type `(string|number)[]`

Comment: `[string, number]` means that it will always be an array of 2 elements where the first one is a string, and second is a number, so basically TS is right here :)

Comment: You want to use a mapped type for the individual indices: `{ [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[K]> }`. No `infer`.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```js
const getValues: <T extends readonly unknown[] | []>(
  ...args: T
) => { -readonly [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]> } = (...args) =>
  args.map((arg) => arg());

const values = getValues(
  () => "a",
  () => 123
);
```